# How to stop AWS Glue ETL Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

As the title entails, how can I stop a Glue Job? I have seen documentations about batch_stop_job_run() but I am complete beginner and I don't know where to add this. Do I inject this in lambda or on another glue job to stop the previously running running job?

Comment: Do you have to stop only via script? Because you can also manually stop the running job from console. When you go to a specific job and click on the "Runs" tab, you can use "Stop job run" button to stop a running job.

Comment: Hello, yes via script. Because on the ui, the button calls lambda that processes the db data along stopping the previously ran glue job.

Comment: Http request body goes like this: {"previous_job_run_id": "previous_job_run_id", "column_data_to_process":"column_data_to_process"}

Answer (score 0):

Never mind found my answer:

```
import json
import boto3
import urllib.parse

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('glue')
    body = json.loads(event['body'])                #GET RESPONSE BODY
    running_job_id = body['running_job_id']         #GET VALUE FROM OBJECT running_job_id 
    client.batch_stop_job_run(                      #STOP JOB RUN
            JobName='entry_glue_etl_job',           #JOB NAME OF JOB TO STOP
            JobRunIds=[
                    running_job_id                  #INPUT VALUE FROM RESPONSE AS STRING
                ]
    )
    client.start_job_run(                           #START JOB RUN
            JobName = 'update_data_table',          #JOB NAME OF GLUE TO START
            Arguments = {
                '--column_data':  'column_data'     #ARGUMENTS FROM RESPONSE BODY column_data
            }
        )
    return  {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "Job Stop Success"
    }
```